# wordpress multisite - can't edit htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting redirect error on my sub sites in my WordPress multi site network, and my .htaccess file keep reverting back to

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

I have tried
-updating my main site and all of the sites in my network
-deactivating all plugins

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php file, add the following lines of code at the end:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Should fix the problem!